# Google Verified Reviews for non online services

Tags: content, user-reviews

I'm seeing websites with images of reviews with a Google Verified Review logo.  However, these are service companies, not online e-commerce stores.  From what I've been able to research, these types of reviews were only available for ecommerce sites.  Has Google changed their verified review system to allow for non ecommerce sites?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "images of reviews"?   Are these sites showing screenshots of reviews from other sites in an attempt to duplicate reviews without penalty?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, that is what it appears like.  There's no aggregate markup pointing to Google.  I take it you would consider screenshots to be aggregating the reviews from other sites?

Comment: I suppose it would be one way of syndicating reviews.  It doesn't seem like it would lead to great user experience though.  Images of text are often hard to read on small screens.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, it's being used by an SEO "expert".  I was simply trying to figure out where the "verified" was coming from.  Maybe they're just creating the image themselves.